# Getting dropdownlist.selectedvalue through Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got this dropdownlist which I populate using programming code:

```cs
while (teller < modellen.Length)
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Mod_Naam FROM Model WHERE Mod_ID = '" + modellen[teller] + "' ", con);
    string modnaam = (string)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
    ddlModel.Items.Add(new ListItem(modnaam, modellen[teller]));
    teller++;
}
```

When I select something in the dropdownlist I get an autopostback (which I use to display a form on the screen for the selected item) but the selecteditem in the dropdownlist get's lost during the postback. How do I keep the selecteditem through the postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely are populating the dropdown in each request. Populate it only during first request i.e. not during the postbacks.

```
if (!IsPostback)
{
    // Populate and bind the dropdown
}
```

Comment: This was verry dumb of me.. Sorry even to bother you !

Answer (score 1):

You should only populate the listbox on the initial load of the window, I think you are re-populating it on the postback which means you will lose the selected value.

Comment: This was verry dumb of me.. Sorry even to bother you !